# Keep disk encrypted until SSH

Tags: ssh, encryption

I was wondering if it were possible to use full disk encryption on my hard drive until an SSH connection is made. All processes on the hard disk would run, under encryption, i.e. the server would still output normal unencrypted stuff through appropriate channels, such as a website.

What i would like to prevent is a company like Amazon or other smaller ones from accessing my data by physically analyzing the hard drive - not a remote attacker, but one in possession of the disk. Even if this means setting up a personal ubuntu server instead, i'm wondering if this is possible?

Comment: On stackoverflow i was downvoted for posing this question: How come when my Android or iPhone device has full disk encryption, I can receive notifications?

Comment: My initial understanding of FDE was as you described, until i was blasted for trying to carry these priniciples to mobile devices. Why are mobile devices capable of running processes under encryption but Ubuntu isnt?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is not possible. To SSH into the system, it must already be booted, and to be booted, it must already be decrypted. This is true for any encrypted device. Phones, computers, tablets, it makes no difference. If the device is encrypted, you must enter a key (often a password, pin, or pattern) at boot time to decrypt the device so that it can boot up. As soon as you enter your decryption password, your data is in a decrypted state. It should be assumed that anyone with access to the system at that point has access the data in its decrypted state.

Comment: Androids and iphones, when encrypted, still receive notifications of texts, snaps, tinder matches, etc.. ? Why can't ubuntu have something similar?

Comment: Your understanding of encryption is incorrect. A mobile device (android, apple, etc.) with encryption enabled, like a physical lock, exists in one of two states: locked or unlocked. A physical lock only limits access when it's locked. If unlocked, it doesn't actually restrict access. Your phone encryption works in similar fashion and is only locked when your phone is powered off or when booting *before* you have entered your key to unlock the encryption. Once unlocked, *everything* runs in a decrypted state (texts, snaps, tinder, etc.). Thus we have lockscreens to protect us after boot.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is possible in initramfs to have an ssh server beforehand but this small part won't be encrypted. You were not incorrect in your thinking, after all there is some software prompting you for your decryption key. The project dropbear-initramfs can provide ssh prior to mounting your encrypted root filesystem for booting. I'm not aware of an out of the box solution but safeboot.dev is fairly close so if you're skilled maybe you can get this working on metal.
2. Your use case of preventing Amazon or other cloud providers snooping isn't really going to be stopped by this. The hardware exists but the software is catching up to provide secure enclaves where your cloud provider cannot see your data at rest, in memory, or even in processing thanks to advances in CPUs and homomorphic encryption. See the Golem project. At this time this is not YET possible but will be soon to:
   "All processes on the hard disk would run, under encryption"
   However you technically can do dropbear SSH prior to decrypting the root filesystem if you can figure out how to implement it.